# What does a little square under the wifi symbol mean?

Tags: nintendo-switch

[image: screenshot of the Nintendo Switch home screen showing the wifi symbol]

My Switch wifi seems to disconnect as soon as it is not needed, and I just realised there's that little square under my wifi symbol.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It’s not a corner, but it is “L”. Based on Reddit threads ([here](https://reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/dy4oen/l_next_to_wifi_symbol/) and [here](https://reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/83zrxf/what_does_the_little_l_next_to_the_wifi_mean/)), the “L” indicates your Switch is using local communication.

This means your Switch is connected to the internet, but the game you are currently playing is using local connections for multiplayer. One of the Reddit threads uses Minecraft as an example.

Another example, which the other Reddit thread noted and I’ve checked myself, is Pokemon Sword and Shield. This icon will appear while connected to the internet, but your game is using local communication for trading and battling

Comment: Also know as peer-to-peer (p2p) / Wi-Fi Direct / wireless ad hoc

Comment: So I guess its the default when you are playing Pokemon Sw&Sh and you are not connected to Switch Online.